# Array of objects

Tags: raku

Let's say I want to connect to two package repositories, make a query for a package name, combine the result from the repos and process it (filter, unique, prioritize,...), What is a good way to do that?

What I though about is creating `Array` of two `Cro::HTTP::Client` objects (with `base-uri` specific to each repo), and when I need to make HTTP request I call  `@a>>.get`, then process the result from the repos together.

I have attached a snippet of what I'm trying to do. But I would like to see if there is a better way to do that. or if the approach mention in the following link is suitable for this use case! https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/day-08-array-based-objects/

```
use Cro::HTTP::Client;

class Repo {

  has $.name;
  has Cro::HTTP::Client $!client;
  has Cro::Uri $.uri;
  has Bool $.disable = False;

  submethod TWEAK () {
    $!client = Cro::HTTP::Client.new(base-uri => $!uri, :json);
  }

  method get (:$package) {

    my $path = <x86_64?>;
    my $resp = await $!client.get($path ~ $package);
    my $json = await $resp.body;
    return $json;
  }
}


class AllRepos {

  has Repo @.repo;

  method get (:$package) {

    # check if some repos are disabled
    my @candidate = @!repo>>.get(:$package).unique(:with(&[eqv])).flat;

    # do furthre processign of the data then return it;
    return @candidate;

  }
}

my $repo1 = Repo.new: name => 'repo1', uri => Cro::Uri.new(:uri<http://localhost:80>);
my $repo2 = Repo.new: name => 'repo2', uri => Cro::Uri.new(:uri<http://localhost:77>);

my @repo = $repo1, $repo2;

my $repos = AllRepos.new: :@repo;


#my @packages = $repos.get: package => 'rakudo';
```

Comment: But what seems to be the problem? Do you get any error there?

Comment: On the one hand, your question seems to me to be [off topic per "official" SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) or close. On the other, your question is obviously a fair one if SO guidelines are ignored, and P6 culture is explicitly guided by [-Ofun](https://perl6.org/fun/) which calls for a friendly answer, and SO culture ultimately supports friendliness and moderation in moderation so your question will hopefully be allowed to stand, get answered, and conclude on a satisfactory note. I'm trying now to write an answer and hope to have time to finish and post it later today.

Comment: @jmerelo: I don't get error I'm just asking if there is a better way to achieve that result . I disliked that whenever I need to use an array of objects, I will have to create two classes, one for the actual objects, and another additional class to hold them (which will have Array attribute of the instantiated objects). So I was thinking there is another way to do that without creating the second class. but I think thats is not possible.

Comment: @raiph: yes I agree, it's  open answer question. I will be more specific in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193854/discussion-between-raiph-and-hythm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Let's say I want to connect to two package repositories, make a query for a package name, combine the result from the repos and process it (filter, unique, prioritize,...), What is a good way to do that?

The code you showed looks like one good way *in principle* but not, currently, in practice.

The [hyperoperators such as `>>`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators):

- Distribute an operation (in your case, connect and make a query) ...
- ... to the leaves of one or two input composite data structures (in your case the elements of one array `@!repo`) ...
- ... with **logically** parallel semantics (by using a hyperoperator you are declaring that you are taking responsibility for thinking that the parallel invocations of the operation will not interfere with each other, which sounds reasonable for connecting and querying) ...
- ... and then return a resulting composite data structure with the same shape as the original structure if the hyperoperator is a unary operator (which applies in your case, because you applied `>>`, which is an unary operator which takes a single argument on its left, so the result of the `>>.get` is just a new array, just like the input `@!repo`) or whose shape is the hyper'd combination of the shapes of the pair of structures if the hyperoperator is a binary operator, such as `>>op<<` ...
- ... which can then be further processed (in your case it is, with `.unique`, which will produce a resulting `Seq`) ...
- ... whose elements you then assign back into another array (`@candidate`).

So your choice is a decent fit in principle, but the commitment to parallelism is only semantic and right now the Rakudo compiler never takes advantage of it, so it will actually run your code sequentially, which presumably isn't a good fit in practice.

Instead I suggest you consider:

- Using [`map`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/map) to distribute an operation over multiple elements (in a shallow manner; `map` doesn't recursively descend into a deep structure like the hyperoperators, `deepmap` etc., but that's OK for your use case) ...
- ... in combination with the [`race` method](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/race) which parallelizes the method it proceeds.

So you might write:

```
my @candidate =
  @!repo.hyper.map(*.get: :$package).unique(:with(&[eqv])).flat;
```

Alternatively, check out task 94 in [Using Perl 6](https://deeptext.media/i/using-perl6/using-perl6-preview.pdf).

> if the approach mention in the following link is suitable for this use case! https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/day-08-array-based-objects/

I don't think so. That's about constructing a general purpose container that's like an array but with some differences to the built in `Array` that are worth baking into a new type.

I can just about imagine such things that are vaguely related to your use case -- eg an array type that automatically hyper distributes method calls invoked on it, if they're defined on `Any` or `Mu` (rather than `Array` or `List`), i.e. does what I described above but with the code `@!repo.get...` instead of `hyper @!repo.map: *.get ...`. But would it be worth it (assuming it would work -- I haven't thought about it beyond inventing the idea for this answer)? I doubt it.

## More generally...

It seems like what you are looking for is cookbook like material. Perhaps a question posted at [the reddit sub /r/perl6](https://reddit.com/r/perl6) is in order?

Comment: raiph: Thank you for the detailed answer. and I believe yes I need to read a programming cookbook, many times I find my self thinking a lot about how to write something, and if there is a better way. is there perl6 cookbook out there that you recommend? I googled but did not find something.

Comment: If you're pretty new to programming, I recommend [Think Perl 6](http://greenteapress.com/thinkperl6/thinkperl6.pdf). It's "intended for beginners and does not require any prior programming knowledge". There's a paid print version of it available. The *Using Perl 6* book that I linked is a cookbook. I like Andrew's writing style but have not read it beyond the free chapter 6. I've also seen two or three free P6 one-liner collections that might be helpful, so consider searching for "one liner perl6" or similar. There are other books and resources; hopefully others will make recommendations.